# why id gives null when sending to controller using laravel ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel

i have in an annonces table a multiple images, i want to update multiple images,I just want to send the data (id,images,token) to controller but it gives me `null` for id

**details.blade.php**

```
<h3 class="jumbotron" id="id">{{ $annonces->id }}</h3>
<h3 class="jumbotron">ajouter les images produit</h3>
<form method="post" action="{{route('filesUpdate')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" id="dropzone">
   <!--<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">-->
  {{ csrf_field() }}                            
</form>  
  <script type="text/javascript">
            var id     = $("#id").val();
            Dropzone.options.dropzone = 
            {
              console.log(id);
            maxFilesize: 12,
            renameFile: function(file) {
                images = file.name;
                $.ajax({
                 url:"{{ route('filesUpdate') }}" ,
                 type:'POST',
                 data:{
                    id      : id,
                    "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"
                },
                 success: function(file, response) 
                  {
                      console.log(response);
                  },
                  error: function(file, response)
                  {
                     return false;
                  }
              })
               //return  images;
            }, 
            acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif",
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            timeout: 50000,
            success: function(file, response) 
            {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(file, response)
            {
               return false;
            }
            };
  </script>
```

**AnnoncesController.php**

```
 public function filesUpdate(Request $request)
    {
      dd($request->id);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace from

```js
var id = $("#id").val(); // val() method used when element is an input.
```

To

```js
var id = $("#id").html();
```